# Stretching Border in UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I thought my question is pretty standard, so I searched Stackoverflow for it, but haven't found anyone who has the same Problem as myself.

I need to fill a UniformGrid by Code and add some border to specific elements inside the UniformGrid, so in the end it will look like a chequerboard.
With Rectangles as children of my UniformGrid I partially get what I need, but the Rectangles Strokes cannot be set singularily.

So tried to use a Border as my child, but it seems the VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment "Stretch" does not work inside a UniformGrid.

My Code:

```
...

myUniformGrid.Rows = 2;
myUniformGrid.Columns = 2;    


var myBorder = new Border()
{
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(48,0,0,0)),
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(1,1,1,1)
};

// This is called 4 times in a loop (with different objects), it's for signalisation 
// that i have 4 borders in my UniformGrid.
myUniformGrid.Children.Add(myBorder);
```

When I run this, the UniformGrid does not show my Borders.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: there must be a style set somewhere. or your uniform grid does not stretch itself to fill its parent. this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your borders do not show up, because you set the `BorderBrush` but not `BorderThickness`, which is zero then. You can also simplify your code by using the built-in `Colors` type. You do not need to set the alignment by hand, the items will be stretched by default.

```
var myBorder = new Border { BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), BorderThickness = new Thickness(1)};
```

If you want to use `Rectangle` instead, you have to set the `Stroke` and `StrokeThickness`.

```
var myRectangle = new Rectangle { Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), StrokeThickness = 1.0};
```

Adding the same instance multiple times to your `UniformGrid` will not work. You have to create four distinct instances of either borders or rectangles. Those are insterted in your grid from left to right, top to bottom in the order of adding to the `Children` collection.

Comment: Ok, i gotta say, I formulated my question a bit sloppy. The Thickness is set, i just didnt use it my question :/
And the comment is only there to prevent to write an loop. Sorry, I'll edit the question

Comment: @Febertson There must be something wrong in the way the `UniformGrid` used or styled then. I tested it and it worked on my site.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot try it today again, I'll try it tomorrow and let you know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the border appearance in XAML instead of the code and see if this works for you:

```
<UniformGrid Height="20" Name="myUniformGrid" Rows="2" Columns="2">
    <UniformGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="HotPink"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
        </Style>
    </UniformGrid.Resources>
</UniformGrid>
```

This should definitely work. Note when doing this do not set the params in code:

```
myUniformGrid.Children.Add(new Border());
```